# How do I use multiple Template Toolkit TTSite views on a Catalyst site?

Tags: ajax, perl, frameworks, catalyst, template-toolkit

I use Template Toolkit to generate views of pages in Catalyst.  To do some basic Ajax, I want to have some output pages *not* use the TTSite style, but a much more basic structure.  Do I put something special into the stash to use a .tt2 file without the header/footer/etc that automatically comes with the rest of my templates?  (site generated following tutorial instructions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, lib/projectname/View/TT.pm has:

```
WRAPPER      => 'site/wrapper',
```

and in root/lib/site/wrapper, I find:

```
[% IF template.name.match('\.(css|js|txt)');
     debug("Passing page through as text: $template.name");
     content;
   ELSE;
     debug("Applying HTML page layout wrappers to $template.name\n");
     content WRAPPER site/html + site/layout;
   END;
-%]
```

So if I name my non-wrapper template .txt, I can avoid site/html + site/layout.

Or maybe even better, I can make a .ajax extension and add that to the list of pass-through templates.

Comment: Nice!  I'll have to remember this if I ever have to pass data back through AJAX from my Catalyst apps.

Comment: Same. Dual headers and footers. :-)